# How to return half of an array short way?

Tags: javascript

so I answer this Q but I believe there is another way
the Q is :

Write a function halve that copies the first half of an array. With an odd number of array elements, the middle element should belong to the first half. halve([1, 2, 3, 4]) should return [1, 2].
and ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) return [ 1, 2, 3 ].

```js
function halve(x) {
  let len = x.length / 2 - 0.5
  let xx = x[len]
  if (x.length % 2 === 0) {
    return x.slice(0, x.length / 2)
  } else {
    return x.slice(0, xx)
  }
}
console.log(halve([1, 2, 3, 4]));
```

Comment: `x.slice(0, Math.ceil(x.length / 2))`

Comment: Your example of _"`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` return `[ 1, 2 ]`"_ doesn't match your problem description

Comment: 1,2,3,4,5 yields 1,2,3 can you double check your problem description?

Comment: srry  i correct the q 
it should be  ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) return [ 1, 2, 3 ].

Answer (score 1):

You can use built-in filter function

```js
function halve(x){
   return x.filter((i, idx) => idx < Math.floor(x.length / 2))
 }
console.log( halve([1, 2, 3, 4]));
```

Comment: srry i correct the q it should be ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) return [ 1, 2, 3 ]

Comment: @ripouu use Math.ceil instead of floor, you will be good to go

Answer (score 1):

```
function halve(arr){
  let len = arr.length / 2 + 0.5;
  let floor1 = Math.floor(len)
    return arr.slice(0, floor1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function halve(arr){
  let half = arr.length / 2 + 0.5;
    return arr.slice(0, half)
}
```

Comment: Please explain your solution and convert your code chunk into a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the length and use `.filter()` to find out whether the `item` is an early `item`, using the fact that the second parameter of `.filter()` is the index to your advantage.

```js
function halve(x) {
  let len = Math.ceil(x.length / 2);
  return x.filter((item, index) => index < len);
}
console.log(halve([1, 2, 3, 4]));
console.log(halve([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.slice(0, -arr.length / 2);
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)